# How to change font size in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

I would like to know how to change the font size in the table of contents. Maybe make it 14pt or 16pt.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Factoring the Group Determinant}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Finite Abelian Groups}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be different from the other parts of the ToC? For example, what about the page and sectional numbers?

Comment: I want it to behave like the default, just bigger. I'm not sure but I think the section titles are a little smaller than chapter titles. If this is the case, I would like to preserve the difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and the command families `\cftXfont` (for the sectional number and titles) and `\cftXpagefont` (for the page numbers):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\LARGE}

\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\LARGE}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Some text in standard size just for comparison.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Factoring the Group Determinant}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Finite Abelian Groups}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\LARGE` you can use any other font size switch or `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont`.

[image]

Redefining also the family `\cftXafterpnum` will give you better spacing between entries:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\LARGE}

\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\LARGE}

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\par\addvspace{6pt}}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\par\addvspace{6pt}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Some text in standard size just for comparison.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Factoring the Group Determinant}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Finite Abelian Groups}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\pagebreak

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} % Rename ToC title

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}\normalsize % Adjust spacing of ToC
{\small \tableofcontents} % Set font size for ToC
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize % Reset spacing for rest of document
```