# How to define the title size of listofalgorithms, listoffigures and listoftables?

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

I have a LaTex code defined as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\begin{document}

\section*{List of Illustrations}

\listofalgorithms
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

But basically, what happens is that the titles of LoF, LoT and LoA are as big as my section title "List of Illustrations". Is there any way to change their title size to something equivalent to the size of a subsection title?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64229/how-to-change-font-size-in-table-of-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the LoF and Lot use the `tocloft` package.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{...}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{...}
```

where `...` is your spcification for the (size of) font used for the LoF and LoT heading. How you do the same for `\listofalgorithms` is up to you (or someone else).

I really don't understand why you put your `\listof...` under a `\section*{List of Illustrations}`. A `figure` might be an `illustration` but I cannot think of a `table` or an `algorithm` as being an illustration which to me conveys the notion of something graphical such as a portrait, a map, a painting, or something similar.